# Var not found in IF statement, but is set correctly.

Tags: javascript

I have a var that's value is set, with an if statement to check which value, then deploy depending on the statement.

```
        function Sort() {
        var Response = document.getElementById("ResponseDiv").innerHTML;

        if (Response == "Verified.") {
            alert("Verified");
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("ResponseDiv").innerText == "Not verified.") {
            alert("Not verified");
        }
        else {
            alert("Else: " + Response);
        }
    }
```

My code isn't landing on "Verified" or "Not Verified" instead it lands on the else statement. I went through several times thinking I had a typo but isn't the same.

The ResponseDiv is filled by this (which works fine):

```
        function Check() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://' + Http + '/ID_' + ID + '.html', false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("ResponseDiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    //setTimeout(Sort, 200);
                    Sort();
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }
```

My div gets the correct data, and the alert box in the else even gives me what I'm looking for, but lands on the else.

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Also, pass information via parameters, not by scraping the DOM.

Comment: Put a `console.log(Response)` at the top and let us know what it shows. You may just not need a period or something. It has to be an exact match.

Comment: `(Response == "Verified.")`  <--  Do you intend to have the period/dot after these?

Comment: You're checking the same element for something in both its `innerHTML` and `innerText`. You should pick one or the other based on your needs.

Comment: [Here's probably what you're looking for.](https://jsfiddle.net/9zda7654/2/)

Comment: Else: Verified.

Is the console log return, which matches the case of the if statement, but I'm thrown to the else.

Answer (score 0):

Debugger shows Response as coming back as "Verified.\n", but in no other way. However statement works fine when coded as if(Response == "Verified.\n").